# Android -- how to use onlistitemclick() function when am using a custom list view

Tags: java, android, listview

Normally when an item is clicked in an listview, onlistitemclick() would get called.Since I am using the get view function to show three text views and an image in each row of the list. so the onlistitemclick() function is not getting called. anyone knows a work around for this??

Thanks in advance.

Sriram.V

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should set setOnItemClickListener to your listview irrespective of your  getview() customisation